# Setting SSL endpoints with Custom Domains on Heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns

I'm trying to set up SSL with my Heroku app but I'm having a bit of difficulty.

I purchased a wildcard SSL through dnsimple and followed the instructions given by Heroku.

I also set up the alias and cname on to point to the SSL endpoint generated by Heroku.
The result of all that is that I can navigate to https://www.appname.com, www.appame.com (but it isn't encrypted), and appname.com(also not encrypted). Additionally, https://appname.com takes me to Heroku's 'No such app' message.

```
# heroku certs displays the message:
Endpoint                 Common Name(s)                Expires               Trusted
-----------------------  ----------------------------  --------------------  -------
randomname.herokussl.com  *.appname.com, appname.com  2014-01-10 23:59 UTC  True

# heroku ssl displays the message:
www.appname.com has no certificate
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Am I messing up on the Heroku side or the DNS side?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the real URLs? I'm not sure how you can successfully navigate to https:// anything and have it be not encrypted. Also, with the appname.com example you might want to make sure that you're using the ALIAS type with DNSimple.